# Why does my C++ application not produce the output I expect?

Tags: c++

So I got this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

    int main()

    {

        int counter=1;
            char letter='i';
            while ( letter <= 'g')
        {       cout << letter << " ";
            if (counter % 10 == 0)
                cout << endl;

            }
            letter++;
                counter++;
            system("pause");

            return 0;

    }
```

And once I run it it gives me this:

[image]

It should give me a loop of letters, but instead it gives me nothing. I don't know why. Can you guys help? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you indented your code properly, you might see the problem.

Answer (score 3):

What is the expected output you think? You have couple of system messages and nothing else. This is because `i` is greater than `g` and your `while` loop condition never trues.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to what boris strandjev has posted, `letter++` and `counter++` should be inside the `while` loop.